# Find word index in string in python

Tags: python, pytz

I have a list and i want to find index of any words starting with Iran and print them.

```
import pytz
word = 'iran'
text = str(pytz.all_timezones).lower()
for t in text.split():
    if t.startswith(word):
       print(text[t.index(word)])
```

the output is 'a' and ',' but i need any word containing iran

Comment: That's because you call str on list. If you iterate `pytz.all_timezones` directly and than call `.lower()` on each of it - you would get expected result

Comment: What's the desired output???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use

```
import pytz
word = 'iran'
text = [x.lower() for x in pytz.all_timezones]
for t in text:
    if t.startswith(word):
        print(text.index(t))
```

List comprehension and `lower()` is used to make a list the elements of which are strings.

These elements are checked with `startswith()` and if its return value is `True`, its index is printed with `index()`.

Output:

```
507
```

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to build new list for simple `for` loop instead of working with the original one

Comment: @YaroslavSurzhikov Yes, my answer has 2 loops. Yours is better.

Answer (score 3):

As i've already mentioned - the problem is in your list to string conversion.
When you call `str()` on `pytz.all_timezones` - you get string representation of list, including all punctuation characters. So, when you call `split` - each word ( except first one ) in resulting list starts with `'` character.

Try iterating `pytz.all_timezones` directly like this snippet:

```
for index, zone in enumerate(pytz.all_timezones):
    if zone.lower().startswith(word):
        print(index)
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code isn't working is that you are converting a list to a string, and as such the square brackets and apostrophes are being rendered into the string also.
So the timezone relating to iran is actually the string: "'iran',". That is the first letter of the string is an apostrophe, so when you call t.startswith(word), it doesn't match.
I take it the goal of converting to string was so that you could turn all of the words to lowercase. A better way of achieving this would be:

```
timezones = [tz.lower() for tz in pytz.all_timezones]
```